# MySQL broke result of divide to decimals

Tags: mysql, decimal, divide

My problem is result of divide process in mysql.

Example:

```
SELECT FLOOR(0.232 / 0.00002200) * 0.00002200
```

Result:

```
0.23199000
```

AND i wait for **0.232**, it mean right is **0.232**
It very important for me the right math result, but i do not know how fix it,
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: I tried to use this method:

`SELECT FLOOR(0.23200 / 0.00002200) * 0.00002200`

or

`SELECT FLOOR((0.232 * 1.0) / 0.00002200) * 0.00002200`

but result is same

Comment: `SELECT 0.232 * 0.00002200 / 0.00002200`, but what are you actually trying to accomplish with this calculation?

Comment: the clear number, and real number - this number, insistence modulo

Comment: Please restate that in standard English. I have a mathematics degree and I have never heard of 'the clear number', and all the numbers in this expression are real numbers, and 'insistence modulo' is meaningless.

Comment: Sorry, i just try to speak English correctly, and do not have enough words to speak right (Correctly), but i think it work now good.

Comment: Check what `FLOOR` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `0.23199` is CORRECT

The answer `0.23199` is correct; `0.232 / 0.00002200` is `10545.454545…` so `FLOOR()` should provide **`10545`**.

`10545 * 0.00002200 == 0.23199` therefore the **0.23199** is *not* incorrect.

---

#### Addendum

Due to downvote / comment challenging 10545 * 0.00002200 's product cannot end in '9'

```
  10545
x    22
 ------
  21090
 21090
 ------
 231990
```